# Understanding &type + 'a syntax

Tags: rust, syntax

I have started to learn Rust. Currently I'm trying to learn how to properly use lifetime annotations and think I have understood the basics quite well. However, I have on several occasions encountered the following structure:

```
fn<'a> foo(a: &'a str, ...) -> &str + 'a
```

The `str` is not relevant it can be any type really, my question is specifically what `&str + 'a` mean (I might not be using it correctly, which is why I'm asking about it) as opposed to `&'a str`. As a real world example I have encountered it in [this tutorial for async rust](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html) where they write:

```
fn foo_expanded<'a>(x: &'a u8) -> impl Future<Output = u8> + 'a
```

I'm speculating that it might have to do with that `Future` is a trait and not a type, but I have been unable to verify it in any official documentation and have not found any source on what the syntax mean.

Comment: `&str + 'a` is _definitely not the same_ as `impl Future + 'a`, and also invalid.

Comment: The syntax is defined here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html. You can see it's a bound syntax, not a type syntax. So you should read the example as `impl (Future<Output = u8> + 'a)`, not `(impl Future<Output = u8>) + 'a` as you seem to.

Comment: To clarify the `impl Future<Output = u8> + 'a` part is copied verbatim from the tutorial I linked to, so no it is not I that has written it like that. From what I have understood from other comments is that the specific syntax where valid for traits until 2015 when it was deprecated in favor of `dyn TraitName + 'a` (and I seem to only get it to work for heap allocations). Lastly I must be missing something but I can't find any reference to the syntax in the link you provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the syntax shown in your post is not allowed.

```
fn<'a> foo(a: &'a str, ...) -> &str + 'a
```

There are two reasons:

1. lifetime generics must be specified after the function name.
2. the displayed way of specifying return lifetimes is allowed only for traits, not complete types.

Otherwise you would get one of the two following errors:

```
error[E0178]: expected a path on the left-hand side of `+`, not `&str`
  --> ./ex_056.rs:11:43
   |
11 | fn _get<'a>(ms: &'a MyStruct, s: &str) -> &str + 'a {
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^ help: try adding parentheses: `&(str + 'a)`
```

or

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found builtin type `str`
  --> ./ex_056.rs:15:31
   |
15 | fn _get2<'a>(s: &'a str) -> &(str + 'a) {
   |                               ^^^ not a trait
```

Thus it's not valid.

As a crude guess, I imagine that you have been misled by not a *complete* type but just a `trait` object. Since such a notation was allowed in 2015 but now it is **deprecated**, as you can see in the following warning:

```
warning: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
  --> ./ex_056.rs:15:31
   |
15 | fn _get2<'a>(s: &'a str) -> &(str + 'a) {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^ help: use `dyn`: `dyn str + 'a`
   |
   = warning: this is accepted in the current edition (Rust 2015) but is a hard error in Rust 2021!
   = note: for more information, see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2021/warnings-promoted-to-error.html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first example (`&str + 'a`) is not valid. The `+ 'a` notation can only be applied to a trait.

Your second example: `impl Future<Output = u8> + 'a` means that `foo_expanded` returns some unknown type that implements the trait `Future<Output = u8>` and that this unknown type may contain references with the `'a` lifetime. Therefore you won't be able to use the returned value once the `'a` lifetime expires.